# Lightning Design SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, lightning, lightning-design-system

I'm creating a microsite in Salesforce Marketing Cloud. My client want to have a lightning desigh for this microsite. 
Is it possible to do this ?
I would like to know if there is any lightning CSS library that we can use to acheive this.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You find everything you need [on the Lighting Design System website](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/)